# How can I reduce writes-per-second when saving player data to a database?

Tags: architecture, databases

Consider a game where the player has some profile or save data stored in a database. What I want to understand is, for things that effect the users score or level, there could be so many factors that this has to be persisted to the database and if it is, this could be many writes per second per player potentially, which could be expensive or slow.

How can I reduce the load on the database while still maintaining critical player information?

Comment: Questions about "what other games do" aren't considered on-topic here. *Some* games do use databases, though, and for those games it *can* be a performance issue to save to them constantly, so there are techniques that are pertinent to that scenario. I *think* that seems to be what you're actually after, here?

Comment: @JoshPetrie Yes that's correct.  I'm just trying to figure if there is a hybrid approach, but having things out of sych is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a game like an MMO (a class of game that often uses databases as the persistent storage), this problem is fairly common. Player data is *very* important, and you will certainly have it in-memory while the player is actively playing because it's way faster to access there.

However, you *really* don't want a server crash to cause player data loss, so you want to serialize the players state as often as possible. However, you also don't want to overload your database with too many writes.

There are lots of solutions to this problem. One that I'm familiar with, having worked on some MMOs, is to define two types of player save events: low priority and high priority. What each makes a save low or high priority depends on your game, but generally things that are economically impacting (anything involving real money transactions, or things involving the player gaining important items, et cetera) would be high priority. Things like current world position would be lower priority.

High priority saves get queued *immediately* when the relevant event happens. Low priority ones happen in the background at fixed(ish) intervals.

Note the term "queued:" Rather than a save immediately going to hit the database, the saveable data is bundled up, serialized into a save *request* and sent off to dedicated type of server that *eventually* saves the data to the main character record. These servers themselves may still store the pending saved state in a database (just in case *they* crash), but it's usually easier to deploy *more* of them to handle scaling, and they're usually way simpler and less prone to churn and bugs.

The main downside here (other than having to, you know, write all this infrastructure) is that the system is only eventually consistent. Without some careful though going in to how the save queue servers manage and prioritize the queues of pending saves, a crash of a game server can still result in *apparent* data loss for the player.

You can attempt to alleviate this by implementing a system wherein the login servers direct the queue server grid to flush the pending saves for a user that's about to log in, ensuring the most up-to-date data. If the queue management can easily prioritize and discard "old" pending saves, this can really help with the eventual consistency problems while still being fairly good at keeping load off the main character record database.